# How to reuse RESPONSE in Apiary

Tags: apiary

Is there a way how to reuse RESPONSE in Apiary? I think that [Data Structures](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#def-data-structures) are not the correct way but I can't find anything else...

Answer (score 0):

Data Structures - as you might've probably noticed look at first as a bit overkill, but it's the exact answer you're looking for. If you're more interested into how to use them in an "advanced mode", please look at a Tutorial at https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/Advanced%20Tutorial.md#data-structures

Another option is to use Resource Model:

```
## My Message [/message]

+ Model (application/vnd.siren+json)

    This is the `application/vnd.siren+json` message resource representation.

    + Headers

            Location: http://api.acme.com/message

    + Body

            {
              "class": [ "message" ],
              "properties": {
                    "message": "Hello World!"
              },
              "links": [
                    { "rel": "self" , "href": "/message" }
              ]
            }
```

The other option us to use plain Attributes (https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#resource-attributes-description)

```
# Blog Post [/posts/{id}]
Resource representing **ACME Blog** posts.

+ Attributes
    + id (number)
    + message (string) - The blog post article
    + author: john@appleseed.com (string) - Author of the blog post
```

And later refer to ^^^ "Asset" as written below:

```
+ Attributes (Blog Post)
```